# Why is the original Altair BASIC (for the 8080 CPU) source code not available on-line?

Tags: basic, 8080, microsoft-basic, altair-8800

As [described by The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2001/05/13/raiders_of_the_lost_altair/) in 2001, around 1987 journalists
and others started asking Bill Gates for a copy of the source code for
the original version of Altair (eventually Micro-Soft) BASIC, written
for the [Altair 8800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800) and other 8080-based machines. This turned out
to be fruitless, but a paper copy eventually was discovered at Harvard
and copies of that now apparently reside in the Pusey library there
and are available for public viewing. Ian Griffiths visited, read some
of the code and [write about his experience here](http://altairbasic.org/other%20versions/ian.htm). (There are
various other copies of this page on the net.)

Since then the source for various derivatives of this BASIC has
appeared on the 'net, apparently without major issues or takedown
threats. [BASIC-80 5.2](https://winworldpc.com/download/c2bfc380-c2b2-c2b4-7d00-11c3a7c29d25) appears to contain substantial amounts of code
from Altair BASIC, and the [6502](https://www.pagetable.com/docs/M6502.MAC.txt) port also clearly has substantial
reuse. Compare, for example, the `PTRGET` routine in those and you'll
see that the header comment has the same structure and several
identical phrases, many symbol names are identical, and the structure
of the code is the same.

Why, though it's been preserved and bits of it are available through
other versions anyway, does there seem to be an issue with making the
early 8080 BASIC source code available? The reasons do not seem to be
technical, since scanning paper documents from that era and making
them available on-line is commonly done.

To be clear, I know that the object code and [annotated
disassemblies](http://altairbasic.org/) of it are widely available. I'm posting this
question not becuase I'm looking for the details of how this BASIC
works, but because I'm interested in the details of the original code
(particularly naming conventions and comments) as written by Gates,
Allen and Monte Davidoff.

Comment: Why not contact the Pusey library and ask them if there are any reasons not to make it available online? If anyone, they should know.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this is off-topic here, at least as long as the only person being able to answer properly has not joined the group.

Comment: @tofro Yeah, there's something that doesn't feel quite right about this question to me, too, but I can't figure out how it's off-topic. Perhaps you could put up a question in meta asking about this and explaining what you feel are good reasons not to have questions like this here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of permission or law, not of technology or history

Comment: Voting to leave open.  I am willing to give it a chance, and would be happy to see an answer, but I suspect we won't get one.  Editing it to "*Is* the source available" instead of *why* would avoid the concerns that this is a legal question.

Comment: I also voted to keep this open, it is _possible_ a person with direct knowledge of _why_ could join this site at some point and provide a useful answer.  Plus, I'm really curious too.

Comment: Who is going to risk even a *remote possibility* of being attacked by a team of Microsoft lawyers?

Comment: It may not even be copyrightable, given that in the USA, software was only covered by copyright from 1980, and was not mentioned in the 1976 Copyright Act. See [Limitations on exclusive rights: Computer programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limitations_on_exclusive_rights:_Computer_programs) or [Apple Computer, Inc. v. Franklin Computer Corporation Puts the Byte Back into Copyright Protection for Computer Programs](https://digitalcommons.law.ggu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1344&context=ggulrev) (PDF) for some jumping off points for research

Comment: @MarkRansom Plenty of people. Early versions of Microsoft BASIC source code for other platforms are widely available. Some links are given in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original code was sold to MITS before it was even completed and teams from MITS and Micro-Soft both worked on it simultaneously. Bill and Paul both moved to Albuquerque to continue work.  It was housed on the Albuquerque Public Schools PDP-10 and edited/compiled there.  I was one of 3 programmers at MITS who worked on it. We also created a version for the Altair 680 computer (Motorola 6800 based).  Micro-Soft got a royalty on every copy sold.  Pertec Computer Corp bought MITS in 1977 and after a lawsuit by the boys, they were given the right to sell it to other companies.  Pertec was not really committed to the product and it was dis-continued after Pertec was sold to Triumph Adler.  I had a copy of the source code for many years but threw it in the trash along with my Altairs in the early 80's.

Comment: Very interesting recollection of events. So I'm led to believe that either nobody has a copy of the source anymore (because it was felt to be obsolete and worthless), or people feel that Triumph Adler still holds the copyright and is looking for a reason to cash in?

Comment: _"...but threw it in the trash along with my Altairs..."_ Ouch. The hardware you trashed is probably worth at least $10,000 today (perhaps even twice that), not to mention the priceless loss of the original source code. :-( But, of course, who would have thought at the time.